# How do I carry an object from one activity to another?

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to right a messaging application, and I have two separate activities. I have the Connect activity, and the Client activity. I also have a class for the client. The client is used in both the Connect and Client activities, but I don't know how to carry the Client object used in the ConnectActivity to the ClientActivity.

My ConnectActivity:

```
public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Client client;

    private EditText txtServerAddress;

    private EditText txtPortNumber;

    private EditText txtUsername;

    private TextView lblErrors;

    public ConnectActivity(){}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        final EditText txtServerAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_server_address);
        this.txtServerAddress = txtServerAddress;

        final EditText txtPortNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_port_number);
        this.txtPortNumber = txtPortNumber;

        final EditText txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_username);
        this.txtUsername = txtUsername;

        final TextView lblErrors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_errors);
        this.lblErrors = lblErrors;

        Button btnLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_log_in);
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String username = txtUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                if(username.length() == 0)
                    return;

                String portNumber = txtPortNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                if(portNumber.length() == 0)
                    return;

                String serverAddress = txtServerAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                if(serverAddress.length() == 0)
                    return;

                int port;

                try
                {
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);
                }
                catch(Exception en)
                {
                    return;
                }

                client = new Client(serverAddress, port, username, new ClientActivity(), ConnectActivity.this);


                if(!client.start())
                    return;

                Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, ClientActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void append(String str)
    {
        lblErrors.setText(str);
    }
}
```

My ClientActivity:

```
public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // for I/O
    private Client client;

    private ListView lstMessages;

    private EditText txtMessage;

    private Button btnSend;

    private ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages;

    private ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage> messageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

        final ListView lstMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_messages);

        final EditText txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);

        final Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                txtMessage.setText("");

                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, message));
            }
        });

        messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage>(ClientActivity.this, R.layout.chat_message, messages);
        lstMessages.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void connectionFailed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void display(String msg)
    {
        messageAdapter.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.ERROR, msg));
    }

    public void append(String str)
    {
        messageAdapter.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, str));
    }

}
```

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't instantiate activity classes yourself, and passing references to activities around, like you are doing in your client class, is seldom a good choice. It can leak contexts, which is pretty bad. Don't do any of those

Comment: @Alexander Hargraves If my answer seems useful then please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Parcelable` to pass an object from one `Activity` to another.

**From your `ConnectActivity.java` btnLogIn `onClick` method , parcel `Client` object:**

```
// Bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("CLIENT", client);

// Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, ClientActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

**In your `ClientActivity.java` `onCreate()` method, get `Client` object:**

```
// Get data from Intent
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle != null)
{
    Client client = bundle.getParcelable("CLIENT");
}
```

**FYI,** Make sure your `Client` class implement `Parcelable`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: @Alexander Hargraves If my answer seems useful then please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ahmed I'm sorry. At the time of making this post, I did not have the ability to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Client class implement Parcelable then pass the Client object in the Intent using

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putParcelable("client", client); 
intent.putExtra(bundle); 
startActivity(intent);
```

[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/03/example-to-implement-parcelable.html) is a sample code to implement Parcelable.

Comment: since the OP puts activities in the client class, it will be pretty difficult to make it parcelable

Comment: Well, I see, thanks for pointing out that. Why are you having activities in your Client class @Alexander ?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for sharing data between activities:

1. If the data should be permanent, store it in a database, flat file, or SharedPreferences. Each activity accesses the data directly from the permanent storage.
2. If the data should not be stored permanently, make your Client class Parcelable and pass it with an Intent. Others have already described this, so I will not go into more details.

Answer (score -2):

You can easly do it by create an instance of Class A in Class B and pass anything you want

Comment: This doesn't work in Android programming with classes which extend Activity.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It works perfectly and I am using it in my projects, but the thing is, you do not have java experience

Comment: Have you looked at my profile? How much experience do you have with Android, not just Java?

Comment: I dont need to look becuase it is clear from your comment! @Code-Apprentice

Comment: You are more than welcome to ignore the evidence. Name calling will only get you banned from this site no matter your supposed experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141753/discussion-between-code-apprentice-and-martin).

Comment: You are legend ;) @Code-Apprentice